# How to get user input from prompt to check in while loop if something is a number?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, nan, prompt

I'm new at javascript and I have searched far and wide anserw how to check user input from prompt to see if user is giving right number. I have tried `result!==isNan()`  `result==isNan(Nan)` and other variations. Could you help me understand why doesn't this work and how to get it work

```
var result = prompt("Give number between 4-10"); 
    while (result<4||result>10||result==isNaN(result)) 
    {
        var result = prompt("You need to give number between 4-10!");
    }
  alert ("success")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the value of result by `isNan(result) == true`

```
<script>
var result = prompt("Give number between 4-10"); 
    while (result < 4||result > 10|| isNaN(result) == true) 
    {
        var result = prompt("You need to give number between 4-10!");
    }
  alert ("success")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your `result==isNaN(result)` code is not ever being run**

```js
// a prompt returns a string or null ( if cancelled )
// The values are casted to a number when comparing with a value of the type number
console.log( Number(null) ) // 0
console.log( Number('5') ) // 5
console.log( Number('') ) // 0

// this means the values of null and '' are never even reach your isNan() code because 0<4 resolves to true. Thus repeating your loop.

var result = prompt("Give number between 4-10"); 
while ( result<4 || result>10 ) {
  result = prompt("You need to give number between 4-10!");
  // you could break your loop if an use cancels here
  if( result === null ) break;
}
alert ( `success: ${result}`)
```

**You could use recursion instead of the while loop**

```js
askUser();

function askUser(){
  let answer = prompt('Hello would you please enter a number between 4 and 10?');
  if( answer>4 && answer<10 )
    alert('Thank you, you are awesome!')
  else if( answer === null )
    alert('Really you can\'t think of a number between 4 and 10??!?!?')
  else 
    askUserAgain();
}

function askUserAgain() {
  let answer = prompt('This is not a number between 4 and 10, you are a fool! Please try again.');
  if( answer>4 && answer<10 )
    alert('Thank you, you are awesome!')
  else if( answer === null )
    alert('Really you can\'t think of a number between 4 and 10??!?!?')
  else 
    askUserAgain();
}
```